# Python parse HTML return words with tag list

Tags: python, html

I would like to parse HTML, get the text out, and return a list of tags that go with each word (or potentially, each text snippet). 
For example, given this HTML:

```
<em>Blah blah blah</em> blah again <i>and then again</i>
```

It would return something like:

```
(("Blah", "em"),
 ("blah", "em"),
 ("blah", "em"),
 ("blah", ""),
 ("again", ""),
 ("and", "i"),
 ("then", "i"),
 ("again", "i"))
```

or:

```
(("Blah blah blah", "em"),
  ("blah again", ""),
  ("and then again", "i"))
```

Is there a tool for or an easy way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use this https://scrapy.org/

For example

```
<div class="quote">
    <span class="text">“The world as we have created it is a process of our
    thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”</span>
    <span>
        by <small class="author">Albert Einstein</small>
        <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
    </span>
    <div class="tags">
        Tags:
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/change/page/1/">change</a>
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/deep-thoughts/page/1/">deep-thoughts</a>
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/thinking/page/1/">thinking</a>
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/world/page/1/">world</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could do something like this

```
>>> title = quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first()
>>> title
'“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'
>>> author = quote.css("small.author::text").extract_first()
>>> author
'Albert Einstein'
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would help. I would like to extract the words together with the styling tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop with a stack of tags when you get to a tag push it onto the stack when you get to a regular word take the last item on the stack and the word and add them onto your list as a tuple. If the list is blank use an empty string instead of a tag to the tuple when you get to an end tag pop the last item off the stack. (By stack I mean list in python just using the push and pop functions to add and remove items)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I was just hoping that something like that already existed.

Comment: There probably is an html parser but it will probably give you a different data structure as an output (likely a tree)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) - [From Review] (https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17657789)